# How to uninstall Application completely from Mac Book Pro using obj-c code?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to create an application un-installation utility.

**What I am doing?**

I am deleting the application(.app) from *application* directory. Code is below:

```
-(BOOL)Uninstall:(NSString *)path{


    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] isDeletableFileAtPath:path])
    {
        NSError* error = nil;
        BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:nil];
        return success;
    }

    return NO;;
}
```

The application is getting removed. However, the issue is that the application icon is still showing in the *LAUNCHER* with a Question mark on it.

**Problem**
1. How to remove the icon from the LAUNCHER after deleting the appliation

[image]

Comment: That data is stored in an `NSUserDefaults` store. Try using `defaults read com.apple.Dock` from the command-line to see. After modifying it, you’ll need to relaunch the Dock. There might be a more official Apple-sanctioned way of doing it, though…

Comment: @icktoofay sir, I am only 1 month new to mac. Could you please elaborate in a little simple language as I am not able to understand what are you asking me to do. S.P I have restarted the mac and the icon is still there with a question mark. I have added a scren shot.

Comment: I’m no expert either, but I’m just saying that if I run the command `defaults read com.apple.Dock` in Terminal, I get a dump of a bunch of data, and some of that data is the applications in my Dock. If you’re trying to remove an application from the Dock (since otherwise it just becomes a question mark, as you note), modifying the `com.apple.Dock` defaults might be a good place to start. The `defaults` command I was using above, to the best of my knowledge, is just a command-line front-end to the Cocoa `NSUserDefaults` class, which you’ll want to look into to manipulate it from Objective-C.